# Why image downloading in Groupon ios app is fast?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am doing the ios app like groupon, where i am constructing the images with NSData dowloaded in background with

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL]
```

in my tableView. But relatively its slower than groupon. What all techniques I can implement to make it faster. And also are there any caching techniques/frameworks I can implement after downloading?

Answer (score 3):

Try AFNetworking. It provides a category for UIImageView that will make your life easier.

```
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking"    
.....
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"theImageURL"]];
```